# "One of those is flags"

Tags: grammatical-number, meaning-in-context, verb-agreement

Jeff Atwood ♦ has [just posted something](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101431/164007) that I'm confused about

> Stack Overflow, due to its size, has some unique problems. One of those is flags

I'd say that *those* and *flags* are both in plural, however shouldn't *is* be plural too? It means, shouldn't it be

> Stack Overflow, due to its size, has some unique problems. One of those are flags

I think it's right, because he's a native English speaker, but I'm just not sure why. Or is it just a mistake?

Comment: "It depends on what the meaning of the words 'is' is." –Bill Clinton

Comment: ?? What are you refering to?

Comment: Just to add to the other answers: you can analyse the sentence as *One of those [problems] is [the problem of] flags.*

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*Those* is plural, yes, but "is" grammatically agrees with *one* in this case.

The sentence is something like this:

> Stack Overflow, due to its size, has some unique problems. One {of those [*problems*]} *is* flags.

The part between [-] can be omitted to avoid repetition. The part between {-} can be omitted to explain the agreement.

So it could become: "*One is flags*".

**EDIT**: I'd like to add that the sentence "One of those is flags" written by Jeff, is perfectly fine. It's *not* nonstandard or ungrammatical. It's correct in English.

Like I said in the comments, "*flags*" is treated as a general noun, not as a plural of many objects. It's like saying "*One of those is the flagging system*".

Comment: I wonder whether the sentence would still hang together if the writer were referring to "flags" as the banner, not "flags" as the programming term for a boolean switch?

Comment: @Aleanno - but, what is correct: *flags are a problem* or *flags is a problem*. So, yes *is* agrees with *one*, but can *one* agree with plural?

Comment: @Unreason: the sentence is perfectly acceptable. It seems wrong to you, but it's not. "Flags" is treated as a "content-noun" in this case, not many objects in series. "Flags are a problem" is a different sentence comparing it to the Jeff's one, I don't think we can really compare it. What do you mean with _can one agree with plural_? The sentence is "One problem is _[flags]_" as in **the flagging system**.

Comment: @genesis: The thing is he's not saying flags as plural, he's mentioning flags as a concept, a whole. It's like saying "The concept [of flags] _is_ a problem."

Comment: @Aleanno, that interpretation I wrote in my answer, too: [flags] = the flagging system = the flagging concept which are singular. The only remaining question is: is it grammatical to refer to ”the flagging system” with unquoted word flags? (what is ”content-noun”?)

Comment: @Unreason: ahah content-noun was a term I just made up. I meant it's like a general noun that refers to something else but it's improper. As in "flags" for "flagging system". About your question, since we're speaking in an environment where if I say "flags" you know what I'm referring to (flagging posts and not the flags on buildings), I'd say there's no need for quotation marks. (Is this what you asked me?)

Comment: @Alenanno, still not clear here - I opened http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37464/how-should-we-treat-a-plural-term-that-refers-to-singular-term so not to make noise here; could you explain general noun over there?

Answer (score 9):

Let me highlight the sentence as :

> One (of those problems) is flags

The "is" agrees with the "One" in this case.

Comment: `The "is" agrees with the "One" in this case.` this is part I wanted to know :) Great, thanks. However, Englishman is wrong? (you edited my question)

Comment: I'm not sure if Jeff is *from England* which is what "Englishman" means. So I changed it to native speaker.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the main reason this sounds wrong is that the word ”flags” is used actually to refer to ”flagging system” or ”flagging concept”, singular. If such substitution is made, there are no problems with the original.

Alternatively, rewriting it like

> One of those is *related to* flags.

seems (to me) more grammatical compared to the original (meaning is changed though; maybe *caused by* is closer to original intention).

EDIT:
After opening a new [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37464/how-should-we-treat-a-plural-term-that-refers-to-singular-term) regarding this subject I should correct myself - there is nothing ungrammatical in the original line and the improvement I propose is just the matter of style.

Answer (score 1):

Note that flags is not exactly plural but it is a feature (not mutiple features , not a plural.)

```
  one is typo

  One is 'flags'  

  One {Among these} is 'flags'

  One {of these} is 'flags'
```

That is how it happens!

Answer (score 0):

(I may be off base here, but I don't believe so, and this hasn't been addressed so I'm adding this answer.)

The *of those* part of

> One of those is flags.

is really a substitute for there being a *problem* with the site, not a direct reference to *flags*. Therefore you can substitute:

> One *problem* is flags.

Here's it's easy to see that *is* agrees with *one problem,* and that whether or not the word that follows is singular or plural is irrelevant. These sentences are all fine:

> One problem is a giant wildebeest in the back seat.
>
> One problem is the twenty-two wet sponges blocking the door.
>
> One problem is goats in my pants.

Comment: Or "One of the *problems is* people focussing on the two words in italics, rather than the whole sentence.".